# How to check Analytics write API calls in cloud console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Node.JS to call the Analytics API to write some custom dimensions. But, i don't see in the google cloud console any write calls for my request. However, I am seeing error in my console .... Quota Error: Rate limit for writes exceeded. But, when i go to google cloud console i don't see any Write API calls.

Here are my functions which I am using in my Node.JS.

```
google.analytics('v3').management.customDimensions.list({
      "auth": jwt,
      "accountId": accountId,
      "webPropertyId": webPropertyId
    }
```

And:

```
google.analytics('v3').management.customDimensions.insert({
      auth: jwt,
      "accountId": req.accountId,
      "webPropertyId": req.webPropertyId,
      "resource": {
        "name": req.offsetName,
        "scope": req.scope,
        "active": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on [so].

Answer (score 0):

The Analytics Management API has a limit for writes of:

- 50 write requests per project per day, which can be increased
- 1.5 queries per second (QPS) per Account ID

You can see all the quotas and limits of the Analytics Management API [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#write_requests)

To view the Quotas and Usage of the Analytics API from the Console, you should:

- Visit the [Enabled APIs page of the API library](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled) in the API Console, and select an API from the list.
- To view and change quota-related settings, select **Quotas**. To view usage statistics, select **Usage**.